# Which .Net Framework version to use?

Tags: .net, .net-4.6.2

I am working in a wpf project which uses two external dll's. One of this dll requires .Net framework 2.0 and the other requires 3.5.

While adding this to my solution it asks for changing the .Net framework to 4.6.2. My application only needs 4.6.1 in other case.

On deploying this solution I saw different behaviors in different machines.

1. In Win10 anniversary update it is working as by default 4.6.2 is there.
2. In my machine Win10 I installed 4.6.2 developer pack, so it was working 
   fine. I uninstalled it, then also it's working fine.
3. In another machine with win7, it works with developer pack, and on uninstall 
   it does not work. Another point is win7 it is not working with redist 4.6.2 
   full pack.
4. In Win7 VM it is working fine with .Net 4.6.1.

Does anyone know what type of behavior is this? I need to embed .Net framework 4.6.2 installer with my product installer.

Is it necessary to have the same .Net framework version required during development on deployment also?

Comment: The developer pack is only ever required on a machine that's used to build the app.  Installing it on an old machine that is not being maintained is not a fantastic idea, uninstalling it is liable to also uninstall the framework and rewind the machine back to its original state.  It isn't otherwise much of a problem, just click Yes when your app says that a framework update is needed.  Currently 4.6.2 is in general release and delivered through Windows Update so that is a good choice.

Comment: 4.7 is also an option now.